# How do I remove http, https ,slash,www from user input in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

i want to remove

```
http://
ftp:// 
https://
ftps://
http://www.
https://www.
ftp://www.
ftps://www.
www.
```

we want to remove if anyone above with domain url.
we want only show url

```
domain.com
```

we try preg_replacefor http and https. its work fine for both, but its not work. if found www or ftp

```
preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', $str)
```

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: @Mike: Yes but then you still need to get the www. out of there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a better one but this should do it:

```
$result = preg_replace('#^(https?://|ftps?://)?(www.)?#', '', $str);
```

- (http with optional **?** s :// OR **|** ftp with optional **?** s ://) with both optional **?**
- www. optional **?**

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler regex:

```
$result = preg_replace('%^(htt|ft)ps?://|(www\.)%i', '', $url);
```

`%i` (insensitive) for cases like `Https`, etc.